# How to search specific word position in array of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, return

A few questions. I'm creating a method that searches through an array of element objects (where each element object has been initialized with [atomicNumber  abbreviation  name  atomicWeight]). I also need to return 'a reference to the element'-- not exactly sure how to do this. The user inputs an abbreviation in main, then the findAbbreviation method is used on an array. The toString method formats and returns each datatype as a String. How might I search for the abbreviation position in any given object for the entire array. And how do I return a reference to that 'element' object.

```
 public class PeriodicTable {

    private final int MAX_ELEMENTS = 200;
    private PeriodicElement[] table;
    private int actualSize;

    public PeriodicTable() throws IOException{
        table = new PeriodicElement[MAX_ELEMENTS];

        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("file name here"));
        int index = 0;
        while(input.hasNext() && index < MAX_ELEMENTS) {
            int aN = input.nextInt();
            String abbr = input.next();
            String name = input.next();
            double aW = input.nextDouble();
            table[index] = new PeriodicElement(aN, abbr, name, aW);
            index++;

        }
        input.close();
        actualSize = index;
    }

    public String findAbbreviation(String abbreviationP){
        boolean found = false;
        int index = 0;
        while(found && index < MAX_ELEMENTS){
            if (table[index] = table[abbreviationP]){
                found = true;

                return table[index].toString;
            }              
            index++;    
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class PeriodicElement {
    private int atomicNumber;
    private String abbreviation, name;
    private double atomicWeight;

    public PeriodicElement(int atomicNumberP,
            String abbreviationP, String nameP,
            double atomicWeightP){
        atomicNumber = atomicNumberP;
        abbreviation = abbreviationP;
        name = nameP;
        atomicWeight = atomicWeightP;
    }
```

Comment: How are you ever getting into this loop? Your condition starts out false.

Comment: You also cannot get an element from an array by trying to use a string for an index. Where are you calling this method from? You are going to have to find the string with a loop and track the index while you're searching for it. If you want the index for abbreviationP then you need to be using a for loop and searching the array until you find it. At that moment you have the index where you found it at.

Answer (score 0):

First, you would need an array or collection of Elements.  This could be an instance variable of the class you are currently writing which includes 'findAbbreviation'.

Second, an "Element" could simply have an attribute variable like "abbreviation" as an instance variable of the Element class, and you may just be able to call the findAbbreviation on the list and search for that abbreviation specifically in the abbreviation instance variable.  It is unlikely that you could search on the actual name to find the abbreviation, because, for example: Gold's "abbreviation" is AU.

Could you show how your list of elements is defined as well as the class that defines the Elements?

If you are simply looking through a list of abbreviations of elements (as your current code suggests), you may just have to fix your current code to do an equals comparison correctly:

```
public String findAbbreviation(String abbreviationP){
        boolean found = false;
        int index = 0;
        while(!found && index < MAX_ELEMENTS){  //this should be !found instead of found
            if (table[index].equals(abbreviationP)) { // you previously had an assignment statement in this if
                found = true;

                return table[index].toString;
            }              
            index++;    
        }
    return null;
}
```

Updating answer to reflect update to the question:

First, you will need to provide a method in the PeriodicElement class to get the instance variable "abbreviation".

This is a standard "getter":

```
public String getAbbreviation() {
    return abbreviation;
}
```

Second, you'll want to update your findAbbreviation method to utilize this new getter:

```
public PeriodicElement findAbbreviation(String abbreviationP){
        boolean found = false;
        int index = 0;
        while(!found && index < MAX_ELEMENTS){  //this should be !found instead of found
            if (table[index].getAbbreviation().equals(abbreviationP)) { // you previously had an assignment statement in this if
                found = true;

                return table[index];  //This will return the object at the index where it was found. 
                                      // Notice I also changed the return type on your function.
            }              
            index++;    
        }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I've added more code. I'm to return 'null' if the element isn't found. But I'm printing out each element. Is 'return null'; (as it is right now) acceptable in java?

Comment: Yes, returning a null object is acceptable.  Since your return type is a String, it is somewhat more conventional to return an empty String or "".  I've updated the code below my previous answer.

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to return the PeriodicElement object rather than a String.  If you wanted to provide a "String" version of your element, to get a meaningful result, you would have to override the "toString" method from the Object class.

Comment: How would I return the actual element? 
return table[index];
Would this be correct? What would return type be?

Comment: Yes, returning the "PeriodicElement" inside your table at the index named 'index' is what you'd want to do.  I updated the code to reflect this.

Comment: If this helps, please accept the answer provided.  If you have more questions, feel free to ask.